Is it possible to run reactive mongo driver without Spring boot and Spring data?
So, we're using spring without spring boot for our project and got to the point where we need to integrate it with mongodb via reactor. The problem is when we start the app it connects to db but doesnt make any changes in db further. There are no any errors thrown also.
Therefore the answer is: is it possible to run reactive mongo driver without spring boot? If the answer is yes, i will appreciate some code examples very much.
My dependencies:
implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:4.11.1")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.13")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.6")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context:6.1.6")
    implementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.6.5")


yes, Spring Reactor and Spring-[Boot/Data] are independent projects

Refer https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-mongodb
